# Y86, getting an ADR. Dont understand why

Tags: assembly, y86

So basically learning y86 here. I have this C code and im trying to translate to y86 assembly. I keep getting this error:

```
PC = 0x2058a090, Invalid instruciton address
Stopped in 2 steps at PC = 0x2058a090. Exception 'ADR', CC Z=1, S=0, O=0
Changes to registers:
%esp: 0x00000000    0x00000004

changes to memory:
```

And basically im trying to translate this c code:

```
int main(){
int i, j;
i = 0;
j = 0;

if(i>j){
    i=i+5;
}
else{
    i = 0;
    j++;
}
}
```

To Y86 code:

```
main:
pushl %ebp
rrmovl %esp, %ebp
mrmovl 2(%ebp), %esi                #esi = 1
mrmovl 4(%ebp), %ecx                #ecx = i
mrmovl 8(%ebp), %edx                #edx = j
mrmovl 12(%ebp), %ebx               #ebx = 5
irmovl $1, %esi
irmovl $0, %ecx                 # i = 0 (ecx) 
irmovl $0, %edx                 # j = 0 (edx
irmovl $5, %ebx                     
subl %edx, %ecx
irmovl $0, %ecx
jg L4

L2:      #else statement
irmovl $0, %ecx                 #i = 0
addl %esi, %edx 
rmmovl %edx, 8(%ebp)                #new value of j to j memory
rmmovl %ecx, 4(%ebp)                #new value of i to i memory
je End


L4:      #if statement
addl %ebx, %ecx                 #add 5(ebx) to i(ecx)
rmmovl %ecx, 4(%ebp)                #assign new value of i
je End

End:
rrmovl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

can anyone tell me where the error is coming from? I know ADR means that the program is trying to write or read from an invalid memory address. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your stack is not properly setup, so you need to initialize `ESP` first and make sure that the `ret` after the function is finished, is jumping somehwere which can terminate the program.

In your error you can see that esp = 0

Comment: How exactly can I initialize esp? isnt it initialized when I wrote the statement `rrmovl %esp, %ebp`

Comment: And where is ebp coming from? `mov esp, ebp` is to create a stack frame, it's not initializing anything. And of course, your first statement is `push` which already uses the stack which may not be existing yet.

Comment: I put the first two statements as they are because in the book I am using a code example started that way. I went along with it since I didnt know exactly how to start y86 code.

Comment: You must learn to use a debugger. If you go by a book, it should explain how to run and debug your code. Maybe there is a CD with a working sample project?

Comment: books a rental so didnt come with one. I got it to work by adding some code. Read alittle more along the chapter and did some research over initializing. Got rid of the ADR exception and got some values to change in both the registers and memory. I ended up with an AOK exception. Thanks for the help Dev!